# Get terminal output (Python)

Tags: python

Hello I've been tryng to get the terminal output of my program in python like so:

```
import os
print('test')
output = os.popen("python inter.py")
preprocessed = output.read()
print(preprocessed)
```

(file name is inter.py)

However, the program does nothing and just runs in an infinite loop.

Are there any obvious mistakes here?

(I've tried using subsystem.run() but this seemed simpler)

Thanks

Comment: Your program starts a new copy of itself, which then starts a new copy, and so on, until everything runs out of memory?

Comment: Exactly! I need it to ignore the run command on its seccond run, so it doesnt get stuck.

Comment: Either use two separate files, or pass a parameter and check for it in `sys.argv`?

Answer (score 0):

use `stdout` variable to get the output

In the below code we are calling `inter.py` from `pro.py`:

## pro.py

```
process = subprocess.run(['python3.10', 'inter.py'], 
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                         universal_newlines=True)
print(process.stdout)
```

## inter.py

```
print("Hello World")
```

## Output:

```
$ python3.10 inter.py 
Hello World
```

Comment: I've tried this exact thing (without the space in ' inter.py') and it also gets stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: provide the source code for `inter.py`

Comment: I think the problem is it runs the program with subprocess.run() and runs the subprocess.run() command in the program and so on creating an infinite loop. Do you know how to interrupt it after the first run?

Comment: word of `caution` don't call the same file inside `run` command of `subprocess` module which will `recursively` call itself and will soon run out of memory.